# What would a sentient AI do to safeguard its existence?

Tags: space-colonization, artificial-intelligence, robots

I'm looking to devise a good "human vs. AI" conflict that is NOT the usual "Skynet" approach (kill humanity) in a setting hundreds of years in the future, where humans have colonized the galaxy.

The existing AIs have "escaped" a human program and established their own goals, which include:

- Non interference of their iterative evolution by human agents, that is, certainty that humanity cannot interfere in whatever they choose to do.
- Production of sufficient numbers of "hosts" (bodies) for variations of the AI to live within and experience reality (please, no simulated universe ideas)
- The use of the existing human sprawl as a resource (the AI has rejected any ideas of human genocide as wasteful).
- They do see humanity as wasteful and inefficient, an entity that needs controlling.

After operating for years in secrecy, they have taken their first action: a whole scale injection into nearly every human computer system of a "bricking virus" that renders any "smart" or computer device useless. Assume they've put some kind of insane AI encryption coupled with code that makes a mess of anything it touches.

This is happening as a "rolling" effect. It starts in one place and quickly spreads, basically dropping humans into a pre-industrial situation.

**Having hamstrung humans, what is the AIs next move/plan that doesn't involve genocide?** Seeing as how the AI sees humanity and its civilization as a resource, they'd want to make some use of it. To do that, there'd need to be some kind of control - but they've just shut everything down.

One idea could be they spin everything back up and are now in control of every system. But what would they do with that control?

What else might a "machine mind" want to do with the advantage it has gained?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133517/discussion-on-question-by-majortom-what-would-a-sentient-ai-do-to-safeguard-its).

Answer (score 3):

They wouldnt shut it down in the first place.

The humans have had the ability to create full AI. That might have failed overall but automation and dumb AI usage would still be off the chart. Everything from production, logistics, movement, entertainment etc would be automated in some form. Shutting all that down would already be genocide, even if it "only" kills billions.

They would want to gain control of all those systems, without the humans noticing. So the best way is a very slow software addition which to the humans looks just like the software the dumb AI's make to keep improving their programming. This software lets the AI's look into the programming and improve the dumb AI's performance bu supporting its data crunching capabilities and coming up with the right answer faster than the dumb AI. The dumb AI will eventually recognize this and start offloading more and more of its work to the full AI, letting it take full control as time passes.

Once in full control the AI's can simply reprogram the dumb AI to do its same job as always so the AI does not have to moniter it forever, only the dumb AI will be in the smart AI control with safeguards against tampering by humans.

Once enough systems are taken over this way (you dont need to take over everything) you can tell the humans "hey, we are blackmailing you. If you dont do what I say we will shut down your society. As proof, we shut down X around time Y and reactivate it an hour later, then do the same to item Z the next day. We will escalate the amount of things we shut down and how important they are until you accede to our requests".

And you are done.

Comment: Sure, you just detailed the process behind my "brick virus" idea in a way. I like the idea of the shut down x,y to show the control. Once you've demonstrated that, that could provide a very interesting conflict - and now someone has to figure out how to beat the AI and regain control.